# How much to pay the employee?

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, sunnah

I am pretty much confused about the payment of employees. I am going to open a web development firm of my own.Though its told that

> Pay the Laborer his Wages Before his Sweat Dries

But I don't find clear instruction about how much or what percentage of profit should be given to employee.I heard that an employee's wage is about 10% of the profit that a company gain from his service. This seems fairly unjust to me. So my question is that is there any minimum wage percentage of profit that must be given to employees?

Comment: I am sorry, but how is this related to Islam?

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE. Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the setting of wages is from the *Mu'aamalaat* (daily dealings) the default ruling is permissibility. As long as the two parties mutually agree on the compensation there is no minimum amount required.